# Why am I not getting Mortarboard badge?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

> Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day

will be the qualification for Mortarboard badge.

Last 25th Jun(2013) I earned 249 reputation. But I was not getting Mortarboard badge. Why is that?

Comment: Because part of that is your association bonus, not earned reputation.

Comment: @TimStone There is no valid reason in that answer. I am getting reputation by answering.

Comment: ok.now i got it